# Google Now accessing Exchange Contacts

Tags: exchange

I just migrated to Android (kitkat 4.4.2) from an iPhone and need to set up Exchange Email on it for work.  On the iPhone, I simply use Siri and it can dial numbers from my contacts.  However, Google Now does not seem to be able to access these contacts in Exchange.  Is there a reasons for it?  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you synchronized the contacts ? I mean can you see your contacts in your dial ? Also make sure you enable the "recognize contacts"( it may be a little different option) in google now

Comment: Thanks much for the input.  Yes, I see the contacts in my Google contacts.  I can also call them up in the phone contacts.  However, Google NOw just does not see it.  Someone said, Google Now only looks at Gmail contacts.  I cannot believe that would be correct??  Thanks again.

Comment: I believe not because i don't have any contacts on gmail i only save contacts on phone or simcard and i still can call them with google now did you make sure you enabled the option in google now to recognize your contacts?

Comment: Freedom,  Thanks much.  So I got it working... Like you said, I had to go into Settings, Accounts and Privacy, Google Account History and activate 'Device Information' (from being Paused).  Then when I fired up Google Now (I installed the Google Now Launcher), it prompted me again saying 'To improve contact recognition, Google needs to use your device contacts'.  Regrettably I had to say CONTINEU, meaning Mr. Google now has all my contacts.  It then worked.  Seems quite different to SIRI as it would appear SIRI searches on the device where as Google takes a copy of the device info. & contacts

Comment: Perhaps I'm being too paranoid?

Comment: No google really have you contacts now but  i think your question should be do  i want to live ultra-paranoid or live an normal life? I say trust but never trust too much nobody google have an big variety ways to abuse its power and if they really want they could access your contacts with easy and even ask for your permission remember that they own android and have many apps on your phone